# Improve a react component's webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am quite newbie with React and Webpack, so I have a (maybe trivial) question:

I have recently created the [react-scroll2top-button](https://github.com/toubou91/react-scroll2top-button) component.

What I don't like, though is the fact that my users have to provide the following configuration:

.jsx

```
import Scroll2TopButton from 'react-scroll2top-button/Scroll2TopButton';
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        ...,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-scroll2top-button/Scroll2TopButton')],
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is there any optimal way to get rid of this ugly configuration?
I would like my users to be able to use my component by just importing it, like:

```
import Scroll2TopButton from 'react-scroll2top-button';
```

and nothing more.

I used the term "ugly", since I am almost sure that there is a way to fix this, after having seen that this is the way the rest of react components work. Maybe I am missing something really crucial, but that's why I came here, to also learn the proper way of doing this, since I have already done it [twice](https://github.com/toubou91/react-lorem) and I think it is not that handy.

Thodoris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package is missing an entry point.

Add an `index.js` file and export `Scroll2TopButton` as default:

```
import Scroll2TopButton from './Scroll2TopButton.jsx';

export default Scroll2TopButton;
```

Or simply rename `Scroll2TopButton.jsx` to `index.js`.

Comment: I think it was improved a bit, but still unable to get it working. What I now have is an index.js which only imports: import Scroll2TopButton from './Scroll2TopButton.jsx'; and in my webpack.config.js I have the following: include: path.join(__dirname, 'example') . For reference, I attach the test repo with which I am trying to make it work: https://github.com/toubou91/test-react-scroll2top-button . Could you please take a look?

Comment: @toubou Is this the correct repo? seems to be different from what you're describing

Comment: the fore-mentioned repo represents how another repo could import my component. I just pushed the `stackoverflow-question` branch in the react-scroll2top-button component: https://github.com/toubou91/react-scroll2top-button/tree/stackoverflow-question, which demonstrates the changes you suggested. Feel free to correct anything there if you feel like also contributing to the code :-) .

Comment: `index.js` does import `Scroll2TopButton`, but doesn't export anything ;)

Comment: Yes, that was just a test, since even when modifying it to also export Scroll2TopButton, it still didn't work :/

Comment: Or B have you seen my latest comment?

Comment: @toubou See issue on your repo

Comment: Cool, thanks! For any future reference, discussion has been continued here: https://github.com/toubou91/react-scroll2top-button/issues/1